# How to let the user decide a font for a button?

Tags: java, android, fonts, colors, styles

Code

```
Button mButton1;
int mDefaultColor1;
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences1;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor1;

 mButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontextfontsent);
    mSharedPreferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mDefaultColor1 = mSharedPreferences1.getInt("Default_Color1",ContextCompat.getColor(CustomizeFont.this,R.color.white));
    mButton1.setBackgroundColor(mDefaultColor1);
```

After Picking Color

```
editor2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CustomizeColor.this).edit();
            editor2.putInt("Default_Color2", color);
            editor2.apply();
        }
```

This is what I used to let the user change the color of a button... I want to do the same for font...  but having a hard time... can anyone help me out? I want to use sharedpreferences for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do in same manner how you have done for color, you just need to save font as string.

Saving font in Preference

`editor.putString("font","selected_font")`

getting back from Preference

```
String fontName = editor.getString("font","default_font");
// make sure fontName is available under assets->fonts
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name));
// Preferred way
Typeface typeface = Typefaces.get(getContext(), name));
```

Apply typeface to your view

```
button.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Here is the optimization part, to avoid the Typeface creation all the time as it is expensive.

```
class Typefaces {

  private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> FONT_CACHE = new Hashtable<>();

  public static Typeface get(Context context, String name) {
      if (!FONT_CACHE.containsKey(name)) {
          Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name));
        FONT_CACHE.put(name, typeface);
      }
      return FONT_CACHE.get(name);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder named "Assets" in "src". Copy a font(.ttf) file to Assets folder and use:

```
Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
button.setTypeface(type);
```